# How to traverse to a child object from a parent object using in test-complete tool?

Tags: testcomplete

I am automating a mobile application using TestComplete tool. I have to get the text of an object from the UI, but the object id keep on changing while change of values. So is there any option in test complete which support -following-sibling or Child Property which exist in selenium tool. So that we can easily traverse from a parent object to track the child or sibling. Please help.

Comment: You question is too general, focus it and add the code you write up to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a property or a set of properties that will uniquely identify the needed object without using its native id. Use these identification criteria to set up the corresponding Name Mapping scheme for this object.

PS. Of course, having a permanent ID for a UI object is the best way to automate tests with the object.